# getting xml post data in a function called with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "xml", 
    url: getUrl('/GetPeriodicStats/'), 
    data: XML.innerHTML,
    success: function(c)
    {
```

I need to get  XML.innerHTML in GetPeriodicStats.
I know it's supposed to be in $_POST variable, but what index do I write for it ?
I tried $_POST['data'], but it's not good...

What should I write in $_POST[???]  ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
dataType: "xml", 
url: getUrl('/GetPeriodicStats/'), 
data: {xml: XML.innerHTML},
success: function(c)
{
```

Then that data should be available in $_POST['xml']